# Stuck using SAML with google

Tags: coldfusion, saml, google-authentication

I have been tasked with finding out how to integrate SAML single log in with an existing application. And Im finding it MORE than difficult to find answers past setting up an Identity Provider.

For a first pass attempt I have set up Google G-suite SAML app...
I have the information ( entityId, ACS url, IDP Metadata xml )

I have set up a URL for a test application, and I'm trying to find ANY information on what to write... I can find NO code samples...Of course I can find other service providers "implementation" samples, but that doesn't help me, as my app will be the service provider.

ANY Help on this, how to code a 'log in' button for google SAML App.

Here is the code Im trying - it's in coldfusion, but you'll get the gist - response is status code 400

```
<cfsavecontent variable="req">
    <cfoutput>
        <samlp:AuthnRequest 
            xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
            xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
            ID="!!!!!GENERATEDUNIQUEREQUESTID!!!!!" 
            Version="2.0" 
            ProviderName="SP test" 
            IssueInstant="2014-07-16T23:52:45Z" 
            Destination="https://CLIENTSITE.MYDOMAIN.com/samlLogin" 
            ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
            AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://saml.MYDOMAIN.com/acs/process">

            <saml:Issuer>https://saml.MYDOMAIN.com/sp/entityId</saml:Issuer>
            <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true"/>
            <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>

        </samlp:AuthnRequest>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <cfoutput>
            <div>
                 <form id="login-google" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=!!!!!IDCODE!!!!!" method="post">
                     <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="#toBase64( trim( req ), 'utf-8' )#" />
                     <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're POSTing an AuthnRequest and the IdP trusts you, you should get back a Response containing the AuthnStatement and any attributes it releases to your application (SP). So you'll need an endpoint set up to receive that Response on your ACS URL